# Is there an open source GIS to view and edit CityGML models?

Tags: open-source-gis, citygml

I'm looking for an open source GIS that supports viewing and editing of [CityGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CityGML) models.

So far, I've found a list of open source applications that support CityGML, but they all seem to be stand-alone applications, that don't integrate with common GIS systems: http://www.citygmlwiki.org/index.php/Open_Source.

I would also be interested in your experience with CityGML in a GIS (also commercial) context.

Comment: I asked a question about this a little while ago - it wasn't specific to opensource tools though. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6406/advice-on-using-citygml-data-and-gis

Comment: You can view cityGML with gvSIG 3D, see http://gvsig3d.blogspot.com/2011/09/patch-to-load-citygml-models-in-gvsig.html but I haven't tested to see if you can edit them so I didn't post as a possible answer. The video shows scaling and repositioning of the 3d object; I don't know where the edits are stored: in the _view_ as part of the _layer_ symbology, or hard coded edits into the citygml file?

Comment: http://www.citygmlwiki.org/index.php/Free_Software

Answer (score 3):

[3D City DB](http://www.3dcitydb.org/) offers multiple open tools, including a [database](https://github.com/3dcitydb/3dcitydb):

> The 3D City Database has been realized as Oracle Spatial/Locator and PostgreSQL/PostGIS database schema, supporting following key features:

and [web viewer](https://github.com/3dcitydb/3dcitydb-web-map)

> The 3DCityDB-Web-Map-Client is a web-based front-end of the 3DCityDB for high-performance 3D visualization and interactive exploration of arbitrarily large semantic 3D city models in CityGML. It utilizes the Cesium Virtual Globe as its 3D geo-visualization engine based on HTML5 and Web Graphics Library (WebGL) to provide hardware acceleration and cross-platform functionalities like displaying 3D graphic contents on web browsers without the needs of additional plugins.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[azul](https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/news/2016/11/11/azul.html) may also be of your interest: it is a CityGML viewer developed for macOS.

It is free (on the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/azul/id1173239678?mt=12) and [Github](https://github.com/tudelft3d/azul/releases)), and it is [open-source](https://github.com/tudelft3d/azul). It does not have editing functions though.

[image]

You might also want to check and follow the list of CityGML software on the new [citygml.org](https://www.citygml.org/software/) page.

Answer (score 2):

[deegree3D](http://wiki.deegree.org/deegreeWiki/deegree3/deegree3D) (part of a broader FOSS geospatial project, deegree) looks like it might work for you. Probably depends a lot on what features you need. Unfortunately I haven't tried it, so I can't comment on its use or reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add there is a data warehouse tool FME. It's a set of tools, very easy to use, also have extensive customer support since it's a commercial software. You can use it for free if you are a student.