# Viewing CityGML in QGIS

Tags: qgis, citygml

I'm using QGIS 2.18 (Las Palmas)
I received Data from a client in citygml-Format. The only Programm I have is QGIS and i have tried everything to open it. It only shows me 13 of 72 Objects of the layer.

I would like to correctly see all the buildings in this layer.

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6406/using-citygml-data-with-arcgis-desktop-or-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, i had seen that question, unfortunately there were no answers regarding QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CityJSON alternative

TUDelft [has recently launched](https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/news/2017/08/18/cityjson.html) a new plugin for QGIS 3.2 which utilize the [CityJSON](http://www.cityjson.org) format:

> CityJSON is a format for encoding a subset of the CityGML data model using
>   JavaScript Object Notation (JSON). The aim of CityJSON is to offer an
>   alternative to the GML encoding of CityGML, which can be verbose and
>   complex (and thus rather frustrating to work with)

The plugin is available [here](https://github.com/tudelft3d/cityjson-qgis-plugin)
You have to [convert your CityGML in CityJSON](https://github.com/citygml4j/citygml4j) though...